# How to Slow Down Twilio's TwiML “Say” Command For Programmatically Making Call From the API?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

How can I slow down a code or the entire message content inside the Say tag?
Right now by default the speed must be set to x100 or something.

You can not understand a word of what the robot is saying.

The code that I am using to execute the call:

```
string accountSid = Configuration.AppSettings("TwilioAccountSID");
string authToken = Configuration.AppSettings("TwilioAuthToken");

TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

char[] charCodeArr = code.ToString().ToCharArray();
string formattedCode = string.Join(" ", charCodeArr);

var message = CallResource.Create
(                    
    twiml: new Twilio.Types.Twiml("<Response><Say>Your code is " + formattedCode + "</Say></Response>"),
    from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(Configuration.AppSettings("TwilioPhoneNumber")),
    to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(phone)
);
```

I could possibly inject a bunch of commas after every character in the text but there must be a clean way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are a few ways you can slow the speech down.

The option you posted is certainly one way. Using separate `<Say>` and `<Pause>` elements will place a pause between characters or sentences.

You can pause things within a `<Say>` element too. [Punctuation will be used as natural pause](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say#hints), so you could separate your numbers with a period to read them out slower.

For more advanced use, [AWS Polly voices support the use of SSML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#ssml). To slow the rate of speech, you can use the [prosody element](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#prosody) with the `rate` attribute. For example:

```xml
<Say>
  This is normal speed and <prosody rate="slow">this is much slower</prosody>
</Say>
```

In your case you could do the following:

```cs
char[] charCodeArr = code.ToString().ToCharArray();
string formattedCode = "<prosody rate='slow'>" + string.Join(" ", charCodeArr) + "</prosody>";

var message = CallResource.Create
(                    
    twiml: new Twilio.Types.Twiml("<Response><Say voice='Polly.Matthew'>Your code is " + formattedCode + "</Say></Response>"),
    from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(Configuration.AppSettings("TwilioPhoneNumber")),
    to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(phone)
);
```

Comment: Thank you. worked well!

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to slow down the voice but I was able to pause the robot in between each number to give the user time to type or write it down. I inserted the `<Pause Length="2"/>` tag in between each `<Say>Digit</Say>`.

```
public static bool VoiceMessage(string phone, int code)
{
        try
        {
            string accountSid = Configuration.AppSettings("TwilioAccountSID");
            string authToken = Configuration.AppSettings("TwilioAuthToken");

            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                            | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                            | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                                            | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

            char[] charCodeArr = code.ToString().ToCharArray();
            List<string> charCodeList = new List<string>();                 

            foreach (var c in charCodeArr)
            {
                string charCode = "<Say>" + c + "</Say><Pause length=\"2\"/>";
                charCodeList.Add(charCode);                    
            }

            string formattedCode = string.Join("", charCodeList);

            var message = CallResource.Create(                    
                twiml: new Twilio.Types.Twiml("<Response><Say>Please write down your login code</Say>" + formattedCode + "</Response>"),
                from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(Configuration.AppSettings("TwilioPhoneNumber")),
                to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(phone)
            );

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Exception(exception);

            return false;
        }
}
```